# How to access Vuex store modules in vue router?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

Here is the code:

```
// store.ts
export type Store = AuthStore<Pick<RootState, 'auth'>>;
export const store: Store = createStore({
  modules: {
    auth
  }
})
```

And the router:

```
import { store } from '@/store'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
    beforeEnter: (to, from) => {
      return store.state.auth.common.isLoggedIn
    }
  }
]
```

When I write `store.state.auth.common.isLoggedIn` TS says that there is no `common` property in `auth`. I checked a lot of questions on StackOverflow but nothing worked. How can I access properties in store modules with no TS errors?

Comment: Not sure in the router but you could do that directly in the component. The Vue router documentation could be helpful here. As for the TS errors, no idea.

Comment: @kissu, yeah, I know about it, but I need in the router

Comment: Silly question, but _is_ there a `common` property in the auth file? You didn't post it. Could you just use `store.state.auth.isLoggedIn`? The only difference from how I do it is I use `store.getters` and it works well.

Comment: @Alopwer Can you show the definitions of `AuthStore` and `RootStore`?